# Copy and paste entire sheet from different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone help me with copying the WHOLE sheet instead of C3:D4?

```
wb.Worksheets(2).Range("C3:D4").Value = wb2.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B2").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wb2.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy wb.Worksheets(2).Range("A1")
```

Comment: is it possible to not only copy but also the format as well?

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly copy the first sheet into the second workbook :

```
wb2.Sheets(1).Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(2)
```